# XML parsing in Drupal

Tags: xml, parsing, drupal-6

I am trying to determine what the best way to parse XML in Drupal is? Should I use PHP or is there a module that might help? For the most part, I need to recover XML through URL requests.

Thanks!
Jane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used PHP's [SimpleXML extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) in some Drupal modules to parse XML data returned from a web service.